# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading csv file in spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I'm on the second chapter of Advanced Analytics with Spark, second Edition.  I'm using

```
val parsed = spark.read.csv("linkage")
```

and getting this error:

```
18/01/16 12:09:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/01/16 12:09:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/01/16 12:09:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:176)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:533)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:412)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63
  at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:190)
  at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:205)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

At first, I thought there was a problem in my dataset, so I checked if there are the same number of commas between elements for each line of all files.  There are 11 commas:

```
scala> import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Source

scala> Source.fromFile("linkage/block_1.csv").getLines take 10 foreach println
"id_1","id_2","cmp_fname_c1","cmp_fname_c2","cmp_lname_c1","cmp_lname_c2","cmp_sex","cmp_bd","cmp_bm","cmp_by","cmp_plz","is_match"
37291,53113,0.833333333333333,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,0,TRUE
39086,47614,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE
70031,70237,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE
84795,97439,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE
36950,42116,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE
42413,48491,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE
25965,64753,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE
49451,90407,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,0,TRUE
39932,40902,1,?,1,?,1,1,1,1,1,TRUE

scala> val fileNames = (1 to 10) map (num => s"block_$num.csv")
fileNames: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(block_1.csv, block_2.csv, block_3.csv, block_4.csv, block_5.csv, block_6.csv, block_7.csv, block_8.csv, block_9.csv, block_10.csv)

scala> fileNames foreach { fn =>
     | val lines = Source.fromFile(s"linkage/$fn").getLines.toList
     | val notMatching = lines filterNot (line => ((line count(c => c == ',')) == 11))
     | notMatching foreach println
     | println("\n")
     | }
```

The output of this was just "\n", so there are always 11 commas between values for each line.

I'm using these versions:

```
Spark version: 2.2.0
Scala version: 2.11.8
Hadoop version: 2.8.2
```

I'm launching the spark shell on a local machine like this:

```
spark-shell --master local[*] --driver-memory 2g
```

The linkage directory is right under where I launch the spark-shell.

Any ideas?  Maybe I'm doing something stupid, as this is my first time with Spark/Scala. I'm also not familiar with Java, if that may be the issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This was a silly issue.  I was reading like this:

```
val parsed = spark.read.csv("linkage")
```

when it should have been:

```
val parsed = spark.read.csv("linkage/block_*.csv")
```

This is because there was another csv file (frequencies.csv) which had less commas in it.  This file just gives the frequencies of a number of columns, but not all.